# Как лучше искать текст в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, поиск

Есть таблица с тремя полями - id (числовой), street (текст), house (текст). Около 250 тыс строк. Каким образом можно быстро искать улицу с домом по полному совпадению, т.е. типа

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE street='улица' AND house='дом'
```

?

Поиск нужен именно по ПОЛНОМУ совпадению. В колонке 'house' тип именно текстовый, т.к. номер дома может быть с буквой.
Сейчас тип стоит именно TEXT, а не VARCHAR. Может лучше использовать VARCHAR(50)?

Comment: Если записей с одной и той же улицей много, я бы рекомендовал сделать отдельный справочник улиц и в основной таблице держать id улицы а не ее наименование. Что касается поиска, то независимо от того, будет ли у улиц id или все останется как сейчас вам надо построить на таблице индекс по полям улица и дом (`create index table_str_house on Table(street, house)`) и тогда вот этот ваш запрос будет отрабатывать очень быстро

Comment: Mike, индекс точно будет учитываться при точном поиске? Или он не используется только при %LIKE%?

Comment: а зачем VARCHAR(50)? Можно и в 10-15 уложиться...

Comment: А в чём, собственно, вопрос? У Вас и так сейчас (судя по запросу) ищется точное совпадение "street" и "house".

Comment: Kvilios, вопрос в скорости поиска. Не будет ли поиск выполняться долго при 250 тыс. записей? Просто сейчас у меня там всего пара десятков адресов, которые наполняются ежедневного по 20-40. Дойдет где-то до 250 тыс. Не будет ли тормозить при указанном мною запросе (с построенным индексом)?

Comment: Индекс - это двоичное дерево поиска, для поиска по нему требуется наличие хотя бы начала ключа. Что бы было с чем сравнивать ветви дерева на больше-меньше. По этой причине `like '%xxx'` и не может идти по дереву, потому вместо начала произвольные символы. Любые другие операции, включая точное соответствие, `<`, `>`, `like 'xxx%'` отлично работают по индексам. Конечно пока у вас в таблице сотня записей оптимизатор может решить вообще никогда индекс не использовать, потому что перебором быстрее. Но когда их там будут тысячи, а искомых значений не много, он индекс выберет

Comment: И скорость поиска по индексу очень высока. Но что бы она была еще выше желательно что бы таблица занимала меньше места и ключ был как можно короче. Поэтому я и предложил для улиц сделать справочник. Тогда длинные названия уйдут в сам справочник, а основная таблица станет гораздо меньше объемом, потому что улица будет занимать только 4 байта (int). И поиску, при движении по дереву надо будет сравнивать только 4 байта полюс несколько на номер дома, а не "улица Зои и Александра Космодемьянских". Ну и при необходимости, по небольшому справочнику проще сделать нечеткий поиск улиц

Comment: Mike, подозреваю, что так и поступлю - сделаю подсправочник с названиями улиц и идентификаторами к этим названиям в основной таблице. Плюс индекс. Спасибо!